# Format hex digits for character code \x

Tags: python

I'm new to Python's `\x00` string formatting and I was wondering if there is a nice pythonic way of doing something like below?  I would like to dynamically insert the `\x` formatting into my python strings.

```
# Is there a way get a similar effect to this?

s = "commandstring \x{}\x{}".format('00', '00')
s = "commandstring \x%s\x%s" % ('00', '00')
```

Some of my strings will be regular text and numbers, but I also need to insert the Hex values

Comment: Do you want the string to contain `"\x00"` or do you just want the character with that char code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\x00` represents *a single byte*. Produce those single bytes directly:

```
>>> "commandstring {}{}".format('\x00', '\x00')
'commandstring \x00\x00'
```

or use the [`chr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) to produce the byte given an integer:

```
>>> "commandstring {}{}".format(chr(0), chr(0))
'commandstring \x00\x00'
```

The `\xhh` notation is syntax that can only be used in a string literal. You could construct the syntax then have Python explicitly interpret that with `eval()`, `ast.literal_eval` or the `raw_string` codec, but that is usually *not* what you need in the first place.

Comment: What about chr(95)?  it returns '_', but I would like '\x5F'.  I guess this is the same value to linux tho so I'm not sure it matters.  I was told I might also be able to use struct.pack?

Comment: @Matt: No, it returns the *byte with value 0x5F*, the string representation uses printable ASCII characters where possible.

Comment: @Matt: you are confusing byte representations with values here. Either you can have 4 characters, the ``\`` backslash, the `x` and the two characters representing hexadecimal digits, *or* you can have the one character at that codepoint. You are not using `\x63` for the `c` in `commandstring` either, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want here is the `%x` placeholder. Try the following:

```
s = "commandstring \x%x\x%x" % (50, 95)
```

It will give you

```
s = "commandstring \x32\x5f"
```

But, you need to pass integers for it to work.